# Prove that the map $C^n\ni (z_1,...,z_n)\mapsto z_1\in C$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that this map is closed:

$$C^n\ni (z_1,...,z_n)\mapsto z_1\in C$$

and I am not sure how to take a closed set in $ (z_1,...,z_n)$. Can you give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: What is $C$ here? The complex numbers? Under the usual topology?

Comment: You need to take a closed set in $\Bbb C^n$, $F\subset \Bbb C^n$, and show your mapping applied to $F$ is either closed or not. What do closed sets in $\Bbb C^n$ look like? Is there an easy way to visualize this?

Comment: Is this true?  It's not true for $\mathbb{R}$.  For example, under the map $$\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ $$ (x,y) \mapsto x$$ the set $D$ of points $(x, \frac{1}{x}) : x \neq 0$ is closed, but $\pi(D)$ is equal to $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty)$, which is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

It's false in dimensions $n \geq 2$.

Let $D$ be the set consisting of points in $\Bbb C^n$ which are of the form $(\frac{1}{k},k,0,0,...,0)$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $D$ is a closed set, being a collection of discrete points.

But $\pi_1(D) = \{\frac{1}{k}:k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which is not closed in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Excellent answer! To the OP, note that $\pi_1(D)$ has a limit point of $0$ but $0\notin \pi_1(D)$ which means it is not closed. But $D$ has no limit points.